# Problems with JSF 2.0 and parametrized EL Expressions

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I'm encountering some troubles while trying to access some properties with parameters. Well, I don't know if they should be called properties since the accessors have parameters but lets call them properties for now.

The situation is this:

I have a Student class that contains different localizations as objects in a map. I can get those localization objects by doing this:

```
student.getLocalizedData(String localizationCode);
```

Now, on the page, I'm trying to do this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{collegeBean.student.getLocalizedData('es').profileDescription}"/>
```

A student's description can have many localizations.

The page loads correctly, but when I try to save  the student it says that the bean collegeBean does not have the property getLocalizedData, tough that one is a property of the student contained on the bean.

I know that line is insane, so I tried to wrap it:

```
<h:inputText value="#{collegeBean.getStudentLocalizedData('es').profileDescription}"/>
```

Alas, again I get the same message.

The only solution I've found is to make a method that completely wraps the studen't sproperty... but that leaves me with 2 methods (get + set) for every localization, and that's only for one property. This means that I'll end having (2 x localizations x attributes) amount of methods!.

Is there any approach I can take to solve this in the most dynamic way? The ammount of localizations might change in the future and I don't want to change any code.

**EDIT:** I'm using JBoss 6.1.0.Final and the JSF implementation that comes with it JSF 2.0.3-b05

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should theoretically work, so I suspect a bug or an oversight in the EL implementation used. You might want to try a different EL implementation (a different server make) or to upgrade the server. If in vain, report it as a bug to the server vendor.

However, since you're actually delegating the `getLocalizedData()` to a `Map`, better is to not do that but instead return the whole `Map` directly.

```
public Map<String, LocalizedData> getLocalizedData() {
    return localizedData;
}
```

so that you can use it as follows

```html
<h:inputText value="#{collegeBean.student.localizedData.es.profileDescription}"/>
```

or, if desired

```html
<h:inputText value="#{collegeBean.student.localizedData['es'].profileDescription}"/>
```

Comment: I'm going for the map. As for the implementation, I'm using the JSF implementation that comes with JBoss 6.1.0.Final. That was an important part of the question, sorry I skipped it.

Comment: EL is not tied to the JSF impl, but to the servletcontainer impl, which is in your case thus JBoss 6.1.0 (which under the covers uses Apache EL, as Tomcat also has).

Comment: I didnt know it! Still the map option worked like a charm. Thank you man! you rock!.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, most EL implementations that accept parameters are buggy in one way or other. The one I am most happy with is Tomcat 7's EL.

Note that you can use a custom EL implementation with Mojarra and MyFaces. I usually bundle Tomcat's one with my applications, so I can trust in a stable feature set being available. You must be careful though, as you can get into classloader problems if you don't configure everything correctly.

Mojarra:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>YOUR EL IMPLEMENTATION EXPRESSION FACTORY</param-value>
</context-param>
```

MyFaces:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>YOUR EL IMPLEMENTATION EXPRESSION FACTORY</param-value>
</context-param>
```